# Condition for logged==true

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want show some option of picker just when user log in.

So I tried====>

I added a global variable in alloy.js>>

```
var aux=0;
```

And in my index.js i did>>

```
loginReq.onload = function()
{
    var json = this.responseText;
    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    if (response.logged == true)
    {
        aux=1;
        homes.open();
        $.index.close();
        alert("Welcome " + response.name + ". Your email is: " + response.email);
    }
    else
    {
        alert(response.message);
    }
};
```

Last part in other controller home.js>>

```
Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    left:10, 
    top: 10, 
    height:50, 
    opacity:0.5, backgroundColor: "Black", borderRadius:"2"
}); 
var data = [];
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({id:'0',title:'Mis cursos'})); 
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({id:'1',title:'Todos Cursos'})); 
if(aux===1){
    data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({id:'2',title:'Crear'})); 
}
picker.add(data);
```

the problem is I tried to use if(aux===1) or if(aux==1), but didnt work both... Always no show "Crear" in picker. Why? Need your helps! and Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not defining your global variable in alloy.js properly.

As you defined `var aux=0;` in alloy.js , so this variable is only available in `alloy.js`. To make it usable in other files define it as following :

In **alloy.js** :

```
Alloy.Globals.aux = 0;
```

To fetch it in **index.js** and **home.js** use :

```
var auxValue = Alloy.Globals.aux;
```

So your **home.js** would look like :

```
Alloy.Globals.loading.hide();
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    left:10, 
    top: 10, 
    height:50, 
    opacity:0.5, backgroundColor: "Black", borderRadius:"2"
}); 
var data = [];
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({id:'0',title:'Mis cursos'})); 
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({id:'1',title:'Todos Cursos'})); 
if(Alloy.Globals.aux === 1){  //changed here
    data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({id:'2',title:'Crear'})); 
}
picker.add(data);
```

Note : also check the proper way to [manage objects in alloy.js](http://www.tidev.io/2014/10/15/managing-alloy-js-global-objects/)

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer, but I still have problem with show option "Crear". I changed 'var aux=0;' to 'Alloy.Globals.auxLogin = 0;' just like you said. there are my codes>>[alloy.js](http://pastie.org/9695468), [index.js](http://pastie.org/9695783), [home.js](http://pastie.org/9695791). The problem is never enter "IF"...

Comment: when are you facing issue when you open home controller using `doClick` method or `onclick of loginBtn` in index.js ?